# AS3 AIR For iOS - StageVideo not working correctly

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to get StageVideo to work in my app but I'm having problems. I need to play a series of videos one after the other, the first video always plays fine but the others will only play the audio, and the StageVideo will show the last frame from the first video.

It's as if the StageVideo has frozen and is playing the video but I can't see it (only hear it). I've posted my complete code here:

I'm testing on iPad2 with Adobe Air 3.2 beta, but have also tested with 3.1 and same results.

Here is my video class:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.StageVideo;
    import flash.events.StageVideoEvent;
    import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent;
    import flash.media.StageVideoAvailability;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;

    public class SVideo2 extends MovieClip {

        public static const VIDEO_FINISHED:String = 'videoFinished';

        private var debugPanel:TextField;
        private var addedToStage:Boolean = false;

        private var videoFile:String;

        private var hwaEnabled:Boolean = false;

        private var video:StageVideo;
        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var nc:NetConnection;

        public function SVideo2() {
            addDebugPanel();

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event) :void{
            output('ADDED TO STAGE');
            addedToStage = true;
            stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onAvail);
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        public function playVideo(videoFile:String) :void{
            output('playVideo: '+videoFile);
            if(addedToStage){
                this.videoFile = videoFile;
                if(hwaEnabled){
                    startPlaying();
                }
                else{
                    output('HWA NOT AVAILABLE');
                }
            }
            else{
                output('NOT ON STAGE');
            }
        }

        private function onAvail(e:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent) :void{
            output(e.availability);
            if(e.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE){
                output('VIDEO AVAILABLE');
                hwaEnabled = true;
            }
        }

        private function startPlaying() :void{
            output('STARTING TO PLAY');
            video = stage.stageVideos[0];
            video.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, onRender);

            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            ns = new NetStream(nc);

            ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);

            ns.client = this;

            video.attachNetStream(ns);
            ns.play(videoFile);
        }

        private function onRender(e:StageVideoEvent) :void{
            output('onRender');
            video.viewPort = new Rectangle(192, 50, 640, 480);
        }

        private function onNetStatus(e:NetStatusEvent) :void{
            output(e.info.code);
            if(e.info.code == 'Netstream.Play.Stop'){
                output('VIDEO STOPPED');
                dispatchEvent(new Event(VIDEO_FINISHED));
            }
        }

        private function addDebugPanel() :void{
            var tFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat('Arial', 14, 0x000000, true);
            var tField:TextField = new TextField();

            tField.setTextFormat(tFormat);
            tField.multiline = true;
            tField.border = true;
            tField.borderColor = 0x000000;
            tField.background = true;
            tField.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;

            tField.x = 0;
            tField.y = 568;
            tField.width = 1024;
            tField.height = 200;

            this.debugPanel = tField;
            addChild(debugPanel);
        }

        private function output(what:String) :void{
            debugPanel.appendText("\n"+what);
        }

        public function onXMPData(info:Object) :void{}
        public function onMetaData(info:Object) :void{}
        public function onCuePoint(info:Object) :void{}
        public function onPlayStatus(info:Object) :void{}

    }

}
```

And here's the code I'm using in frame:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var vid:SVideo2 = new SVideo2();
addChild(vid);

var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();
btn.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
btn.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 40);
btn.x = 462;
btn.y = 518;
btn.width = 100;
btn.height = 40;

addChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent) :void{
    var rand:String = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 37));
    vid.playVideo('mp4/result_'+rand+'.mp4');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fighting with this bug, and completely re-writing the code, I found that the reason was because I did not clear the netStream reference attached to the StageVideo, i.e; `StageVideo.attachNetStream(null)`;

This needs to be cleared before/after each new video is played.

> Before calling attachNetStream() a second time, call the currently
>   attached NetStream object's close() method. Calling close() releases
>   all the resources, including hardware decoders, involved with playing
>   the video. Then you can call attachNetStream() with either another
>   NetStream object or null.

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html#attachNetStream%28%29

Answer (score 0):

have you set backgroundAlpha = 0 ? -> s:Application backgroundAlpha=0